# Trouble creating a nesting dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a specific nesting dictionary for an assignment (don't worry, I already have permission to post this here!), and I'm running into a strange error that I can't make sense of. The code is a bit long, so I'm just posting the area where I know the error is taking place (including the tags I've used for troubleshooting and the results showing the errors). I've bolded a clean example of what the error is.

### NOTES

csv_dict= Dictionary of all the items that 
are being pulled from. I’m showing a mini version of 
this because it’s very long (20 values for each key; 
the first number in each value is a unique ID given to 
each person:

{'Address': [{'17': 'Ap #929-9420 Vivamus Rd.', '16…
      'Name': [{'17': 'Meredith F. Clayton', '16'…
 ‘Email’...

### CODE

```
assignment_dict = {0 : 'Name', 1: 'Phone', 2: 'Address', 3 : 'City', 4: 'Country', 5: 'Email'}

csv_step1 = {}

csv_file = {'Name': [], 'Phone': [], 'Address': [], 'City': [], 'Country': [], 'Email': []}

counter = 0
while counter < 2:
    list_of_dicts_to_convert = csv_dict[assignment_dict[counter]]
    for csv_dict_value in list_of_dicts_to_convert:
        for key, value in csv_dict_value.items():
            csv_step1[key] = value
    print(assignment_dict[counter], csv_step1)
    csv_file[assignment_dict[counter]] = csv_step1
    print(csv_file, "\n\n")
    counter += 1


print("Final csv_file:", csv_file)
```

### RESULTS

Name {'5': 'Jescie Sargent', '19': 'Gabriel Richmond', '7': 'Bevis M. Santos', '6': 'Kessie Morgan', '9': 'Charles F. Crawford', '13': 'Katelyn Munoz', '11': 'Elijah Myers', '3': 'Alexandra E. Saunders', '16': 'Tatyana H. French', '14': 'Genevieve Holland', '17': 'Meredith F. Clayton', '15': 'Wesley Z. Sharp', '0': 'Hillary Benton', '2': 'Camden Z. Blair', '12': 'Thane Burch', '1': 'Morgan Y. Little', '8': 'Flynn Alston', '4': 'Hanae P. Walsh', '10': 'Cairo Wolfe', '18': 'Rajah Carrillo'}

Current csv_file: {'Address': [], '**Name': {'5': 'Jescie Sargent'**, '19': 'Gabriel Richmond', '7': 'Bevis M. Santos', '6': 'Kessie Morgan', '9': 'Charles F. Crawford', '13': 'Katelyn Munoz', '11': 'Elijah Myers', '3': 'Alexandra E. Saunders', '16': 'Tatyana H. French', '14': 'Genevieve Holland', '17': 'Meredith F. Clayton', '15': 'Wesley Z. Sharp', '0': 'Hillary Benton', '2': 'Camden Z. Blair', '12': 'Thane Burch', '1': 'Morgan Y. Little', '8': 'Flynn Alston', '4': 'Hanae P. Walsh', '10': 'Cairo Wolfe', '18': 'Rajah Carrillo'}, 'Country': [], 'Phone': [], 'Email': [], 'City': []}

Phone {'5': '265-1176', '19': '1-387-932-2096', '7': '227-9994', '6': '945-0713', '9': '791-5111', '13': '220-5054', '11': '1-238-336-4864', '3': '1-637-740-7614', '16': '1-120-782-6047', '14': '992-6968', '17': '425-7583', '15': '1-960-740-2261', '0': '1-243-669-7472', '2': '123-5058', '12': '1-894-978-3696', '1': '155-3483', '8': '398-8097', '4': '901-2461', '10': '1-930-942-2322', '18': '1-576-789-5730'}

Current csv_file: {'Address': [], **'Name': {'5': '265-1176'**, '19': '1-387-932-2096', '7': '227-9994', '6': '945-0713', '9': '791-5111', '13': '220-5054', '11': '1-238-336-4864', '3': '1-637-740-7614', '16': '1-120-782-6047', '14': '992-6968', '17': '425-7583', '15': '1-960-740-2261', '0': '1-243-669-7472', '2': '123-5058', '12': '1-894-978-3696', '1': '155-3483', '8': '398-8097', '4': '901-2461', '10': '1-930-942-2322', '18': '1-576-789-5730'}, 'Country': [], **'Phone': {'5': '265-1176',** '19': '1-387-932-2096', '7': '227-9994', '6': '945-0713', '9': '791-5111', '13': '220-5054', '11': '1-238-336-4864', '3': '1-637-740-7614', '16': '1-120-782-6047', '14': '992-6968', '17': '425-7583', '15': '1-960-740-2261', '0': '1-243-669-7472', '2': '123-5058', '12': '1-894-978-3696', '1': '155-3483', '8': '398-8097', '4': '901-2461', '10': '1-930-942-2322', '18': '1-576-789-5730'}, 'Email': [], 'City': []}

Final csv_file: {'Address': [], **'Name': {'5': '265-1176'**, '19': '1-387-932-2096', '7': '227-9994', '6': '945-0713', '9': '791-5111', '13': '220-5054', '11': '1-238-336-4864', '3': '1-637-740-7614', '16': '1-120-782-6047', '14': '992-6968', '17': '425-7583', '15': '1-960-740-2261', '0': '1-243-669-7472', '2': '123-5058', '12': '1-894-978-3696', '1': '155-3483', '8': '398-8097', '4': '901-2461', '10': '1-930-942-2322', '18': '1-576-789-5730'}, 'Country': [], **'Phone': {'5': '265-1176',** '19': '1-387-932-2096', '7': '227-9994', '6': '945-0713', '9': '791-5111', '13': '220-5054', '11': '1-238-336-4864', '3': '1-637-740-7614', '16': '1-120-782-6047', '14': '992-6968', '17': '425-7583', '15': '1-960-740-2261', '0': '1-243-669-7472', '2': '123-5058', '12': '1-894-978-3696', '1': '155-3483', '8': '398-8097', '4': '901-2461', '10': '1-930-942-2322', '18': '1-576-789-5730'}, 'Email': [], 'City': []}

### PROBLEM:

For some reason, the phone numbers are replacing the names in the names section even though the loop should only be filling the values for key of the current value of csv_file[assignment_dict[counter]]. If I put in the full loop (populating Email, City, Country and Address), Email will end up replacing all of them in the end (since it's the last in the loop).

I’m trying to prevent this, but everything I’ve tried so far has failed. Any idea on how to get this to populate correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

difficult to guess without knowing what is csv_dict and what is assignment_dict. Here is one guess:

are you missing csv_step1 = {} initialization in while loop?

Comment: Sorry about that. assignment_dict = {0 : 'Name', 1: 'Phone', 2: 'Address',  3 : 'City', 4: 'Country', 5: 'Email'}
I'm posting csv_dict in another reply because I've been haven't issues formatting.

Comment: did you try initializing csv_step1 in while loop? did it help?

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I did rewrite it a little to put the csv_step1 = {} in the loop (I had it outside before obviously) and it worked! I think I now have at least a basic understanding of why it was failing.

Comment: i am glad it helped. best wishes.